# Retrieve data from MySQL table stored as milliseconds

Tags: mysql, timestamp, milliseconds

I have a field named premium_end_date, and I run a query to retrieve a date that is smaller than premium_end_daten, the field records are stored as milliseconds:

```
mysql> SELECT id_prem, premium_end_date FROM ads_premium LIMIT 1;
+---------+------------------+
| id_prem | premium_end_date |
+---------+------------------+
|       1 |       1633967568 |
+---------+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

The table looks like:

```
mysql> describe ads_premium;
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field              | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id_prem            | int unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| premium_views      | bigint       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| premium_start_date | bigint       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| premium_end_date   | bigint       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
10 rows in set (0.03 sec)
```

I run this query:

```
/** code here */
WHERE premium_end_date >= CURDATE()
/** code here */
```

But as the record is in milliseconds, it does not return anything, and I do not want to change the field from bigint to another one, as I have a lot of data inside

Comment: That looks like a TIMESTAMP to me, how do you store data into that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks like a straight forward unix timestamp to me.

If you run,

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(1633967568);
```

Do you get a date like  `2021-10-11 15:52:48`

So you can select using

```
WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(premium_end_date) >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
```

Comment: Yes I've got that format, how can I select as `WHERE premium_end_date >= CURDATE()`

Comment: There is only a little issue, is that CURRENT_TIMESTAMP is better than CURDATE in my case, because I use time (h:i:s)

Comment: Great! If you notice it was you that mentioned curdate() :)

Comment: As your bigint is actually the same as a timestamp datatype, converting it would be easy

Comment: I would like to increase the reputation, but I should have 15 reputations and above, thanks RiggsFolly, may be next time